# R - comparing two rows by columns and writing the result in a table

Tags: r, seq

I'm an R newbie and probably the solution for my problem is very simple but it's out of my reach for now...
I would like to compare rows in a data frame by columns. The data in each column is a letter (nucleotide base):

```
seq1 A C T G T
seq2 A C G G G
seq3 A G G C A
...
```

I'd like to compare all rows in the data set with each other by column. The result I would like to obtain is simple 1 or 0 for TRUE and FALSE in the comparison, written in a form of table as well. So it would look like this:

```
seq1_seq2 1 1 0 1 0
seq1_seq3 1 0 0 0 0
seq2_seq3 1 0 1 0 0
...
```

My skills in R are too low to write something useful. However, I managed to find out that

```
ifelse(data[1,]==data[2,], 1, 0)
```

returns almost what I need although without showing which rows are compared (no seq1_seq2 column). 
I would appreciate any help on this problem. Of course, an example of complete solution would be the most desired but I will be gratefull also for any suggestions about how to solve this problem.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Storing sequences in dataframe by rows is wrong.  You should store sequences by columns, or, if you store them by rows, at least do it in a matrix rather than dataframe.  Below I assume you use a matrix.  You can transform dataframe to a matrix with `as.matrix` function.

If you want to avoid loops, you should use `combn` for such tasks

```
> a
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
seq1 "A"  "C"  "T"  "G"  "T" 
seq2 "A"  "C"  "G"  "G"  "G" 
seq3 "A"  "G"  "G"  "C"  "A" 

> compare = t(combn(nrow(a),2,FUN=function(x)a[x[1],]==a[x[2],]))
> rownames(compare) = combn(nrow(a),2,FUN=function(x)paste0("seq",x[1],"_seq",x[2]))

> compare
          [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
seq1_seq2 TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
seq1_seq3 TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
seq2_seq3 TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

To transform booleans to integers (if you really need it):

> storage.mode(compare) = "integer"

Comment: This solution is considerably faster even as it does the n-squared computation. So, I would go with this one instead of the double loop.

Comment: @Gopala in terms of asymptotic speed, all three solutions are the same.  If n is number of elements in a sequence (5 in the example), the computation is O(n).

Comment: Yes, I understand that....it is n-squared operations. However, `combn` is executing the loop much more efficiently is the point I was trying to make.

Comment: I would like to thank everyone for their responses! Guys, you are awesome!
I have tested all solutions and marked user31264 response as the one solving problem, since it was the fastest. Dominic's answer worked great on small, test data set. However, I tried this on approx 1800 sequences and Gopala's script consumed my all 16Gb RAM within 20min, resulting in crash of the R session.
User31264's solution was as Gopala noticed, considerably faster. On the 1800 seq data set it generated over 500Mb result file within 5 minutes.
Again, big thanks to all who responded!

Answer (score 1):

In this case, since you want all n-squared comparisons done, looping this way is one option:

```
result <- list()
for (i in 1:(nrow(df) - 1)) {
    for (j in (i + 1):nrow(df)) {
      result[[paste(row.names(df)[i], row.names(df)[j], sep = '_')]] <- as.integer(df[i, ] == df[j, ])
    }
}
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, result))
```

Resulting output will be as follows:

```
          V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
seq1_seq2  1  1  0  1  0
seq1_seq3  1  0  0  0  0
seq2_seq3  1  0  1  0  0
```

Of course, this will be very slow for larger data sets.

Comment: for i in 1:(nrow(df)-1); for j in (i+1):nrow(df)

Comment: I was just literally making that edit noticing my error in avoiding extra computations.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat different approach than Gopala's... There's probably a simpler way to get there, but here it is:

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
myData <- data.frame(n1=c("A","A","A"),n2=c("C","C","G"),
                     n3=c("T","G","G"),n4=c("G","G","C"),n5=c("T","G","A"))
rownames(myData) <- paste0("seq",1:3)

# Generate all combinations for comparisons
compar <- apply(combn(rownames(myData),2),2,paste0)

# Create a temporary list having pairs of rows
myList <- apply(compar, 2, function(r) myData[r,])
names(myList) <- apply(combn(rownames(myData),2),2,paste0,collapse="_")

# Compare the two rows for each element in the list
results <- t(sapply(myList, function(x) as.numeric(x[1,]==x[2,])))
colnames(results) <- colnames(myData)

results

          n1 n2 n3 n4 n5
seq1_seq2  1  1  0  1  0
seq1_seq3  1  0  0  0  0
seq2_seq3  1  0  1  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code (it uses `myData` from the @Dominic Comtois's answer):

```
m <- combn(nrow(myData),2)

result <- sapply(myData,function(C) {z=C[m];z[c(TRUE,FALSE)]==z[c(FALSE,TRUE)]})
#       n1    n2    n3    n4    n5
#[1,] TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#[2,] TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[3,] TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

How it works:

1. `combn` generates all possible pairs of row indices
2. `sapply` loops over each column of `myData`
3. For each column, obtain a vector analogue of matrix `m` in which row indices are substituted by the values from `myData`
4. Odd elements of this vector contain first row, and even elements contain second row, thus we can use bit mask c(TRUE,FALSE) and c(FALSE,TRUE) for the comparison of odd/even elements.